# Is there any way to store a graph in a database so it remains easily traversible?

Tags: database, algorithm, graph

If I have a large graph, how can I store it so that it is still easily traversible *preferably* without having to pull it back out into memory. This question is both platform- and language-agnostic. I'll pick the language and platform that fits the problem, rather than trying to forcibly solve the problem with the wrong platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a graph database would fit your needs. Neo4J is a java implementation of such a database system

Comment: Thank you! As I said in another comment, I didn't even know graph databases were a thing. This is great, because I would rather do things natively than go through the headache of mashing a graph into a table. Bonus points for naming a graph database that looks good as well.

Answer (score 1):

There exist database systems that are specifically tailored for that purpose, namely [graph databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database). I haven't used any myself, but the article lists several such systems, some of which are free.

For completeness: it is possible, but cumbersome (and not very efficient) to work with a graph stored in a regular SQL database without loading all of it into memory. As an example of what's possible, a friend of mine [implemented Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm in T-SQL](http://hansolav.net/blog/ImplementingDijkstrasAlgorithmUsingTSQL.aspx)...

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that graph databases were a thing before now, so this is really helpful. I spent all morning thinking about how to do something like in the second link you posted, but a graph database that can do it natively will be a lifesaver.

Comment: @NickAnderegg: I like your pragmatic "I'll pick the tool that does the job best" attitude! :-)

Comment: I know C, C++, Java, PHP, Python, JavaScript, Visual Basic, some Ruby, and a bit of Perl. PHP is my go-to language for building web applications quickly, but it would be stupid to stick to one language and platform because it's what I know best. I hate when people argue about "which language is better" or why one language sucks. Each has its use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply store the graph as a list of nodes, attaching a unique ID to each of the nodes, and storing the list of adjacent node IDs along with the node.

So you can basically see the adjacent node IDs without pulling the whole graph from the database, and query the database for the adjacent nodes. (Node ID is a good candidate for primary key.)

Comment: I was thinking about this technique, but that would be one massive headache. I'd have to write an entire system just to manipulate a graph that is in an relational database, but I'd much prefer to handle it natively.

Comment: @Nick: yes, it's true. But the procedures should be relatively simple. Anyway, a specialized system is a way to go, provided you can you one. (The specialized systems were covered in another answers.)

Answer (score 0):

Databases increasingly have functionality to help with problems, such as graph traversal.

SQL Server offers recursive CTEs, which are well-suited for this purpose.  Oracle has "connect by", which can serve the same purpose.

Whether this is "easy" or not depends on your SQL programming skills.  I'm guessing the answer is no.

However, if you have a system that is well suited for a database, apart from the need to traverse such a graph, you can fit the graph into many database systems.

Comment: My SQl skills aren't the issue, it's more an issue of execution time. Traversal in a database like MySQL would require me to get a node, read the data, decide if I want to traverse it, pull the nodes it points to, decide which one of those, etc., etc. It's all much easier to handle in a system that can operate on graphs natively.

Comment: Hmmm, it depends if you are looking for one path at a time or many paths.  The SQL constructs I mentioned would find many paths at once.  You can then use SQL to label, measure, select, or do what you want with them.